# matplotlib animation close event

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I uses the animation.FuncAnimation from matplotlib to view camera pictures. I use python 3.6. Is there a possibility to attach a function to the close event?

My goal is:
If I close the window, I would also like to close the camera. I just want to close the window of the animation not the whole python application. What is the best way to do this?

```
from Class.LiveView import LiveView
from Class.PixelFormat import PixelFormat
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

class Viewer(object):
   """show picture"""
   def __init__ (self):
      self.cap = LiveView()
      self.cap.startcam()
      self.cap.autoExposureTime()

   def plotPicLive(self):
      self.cap.startGetPic(PixelFormat.Mono8)
      fig = plt.figure()
      frame = self.cap.getPic()
      fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
      im = plt.imshow(frame, animated=True)
      def updatefig(*args):
         frame = self.cap.getPic()
         im.set_array(frame)
         return im
      ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,updatefig, interval=1)
      plt.show()

   def close(self):
      self.cap.stopPic()
      self.cap.close()
      self.cap.cleanCam()
```

This is only a example class.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matplotlib has a `close_event`. This is unfortunately not well documented in the [event handling guide](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html) but there is [an example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/close_event.html) on how to use it. To cite the example:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def handle_close(evt):
    print('Closed Figure!')

fig = plt.figure()
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('close_event', handle_close)

plt.text(0.35, 0.5, 'Close Me!', dict(size=30))
plt.show()
```

In your case, (under the assumption that the rest of the code works fine) this could be directly used as

```
      # .....

      ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,updatefig, interval=1)
      fig.canvas.mpl_connect('close_event', self.close)
      plt.show()

   def close(self):
      self.cap.stopPic()
      self.cap.close()
      self.cap.cleanCam()
```